# How can i change android launcher application programmatically?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have two launcher application in my android device. how can i choose one programmatically from my flutter application.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean how to choose? You mean to select one of them to be the default launcher? Or to launch one of them directly without showing this prompt?

Comment: Choosing one of them directly without showing prompt.

Comment: I want to choose one of them programmatically from my flutter application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [device_apps](https://pub.dev/packages/device_apps) which can list installed applications, listen to app changes and also open the one you want. Here is an example of opening an application (replace the package name with the one you wish to launch):

```
DeviceApps.openApp('com.package.example');
```